# python argwhere with and as well as or

Tags: python, numpy, boolean

I am trying to use python's `numpy.argwhere` to return the indexes of an array meeting various multiple conditions.

I am having an issue implementing `&` as well as `or` into the multiple conditions.

for example 
x y and z are arrays with the same length that represent simultaneous time series of different variables.

`np.argwhere((x>2) & (y=0) & (z>-1) & (z<1)).squeeze()`

is simple and works

but I can't get it to work to find where `z<-1` or `z>1` along with the other conditions met as well.

I keep getting

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

after many logical ways of using parenthesis.

Comment: `argwhere` is just the transpose of `where`.  All either do is identify where `(x>2) & (y=0) & (z>-1) & (z<1)` boolean array is True.  To avoid that `ambiguity` error, pay close attention to the `()`, and use `|` instead of `or` (or `and`).

Comment: i never knew that "|" could be used as "or" in python  so i could use an expression like this np.argwhere((x>2) & (z<-1) | (z>1) & (y==0))   and it would give me the desired reslts

Comment: '|' is a `numpy` use, not general Python.  It's the elementwise 'or', `np.logical_or`.  The Python 'or' has a short circuiting behavior that doesn't play well with the numpy boolean operations.

Comment: so within a numpy functions arguments it serves that purpose